# Cant assign string to single char variable for playing card program in C

Tags: c, string, if-statement, char

I'm learning C and trying to write a simple program that takes the the abbreviated input for a playing card and outputs a sentence. For example, the input 9H would be "Nine of Hearts" or 14S would be "Ace of Spades" where 11, 12, 13 and 14 would be Jack, Queen, King, and Ace respectively.

The problem i'm having is taking the input of a single char and assigning it a string value like "Diamonds".

I know there is probably a much more elegant way to do this, but I'm pretty new. Am I totally on the wrong track?

my compiler is giving me "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"

What is the proper way to do this? i'm completely stuck.

here is what I have so far.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
{
//Declarations

   char suit = "";

   int rank = 0;


//Input

   printf("Enter card:  ");
   scanf("%d%c", rank, suit);



//Process



   if(rank = 14)
      printf("Ace of %c", suit);
   else if (rank = 13)
      printf("King of %c", suit);
   else if (rank = 12)
      printf("Queen of %c", suit);
   else if (rank = 11)
      printf("Jack of %c", suit);
   else if (rank = 10)
      printf("Ten of %c", suit);
   else if (rank = 9)
      printf("Nine of %c", suit);
   else if (rank = 8)
      printf("Eight of %c", suit);
   else if (rank = 7)
      printf("Seven of %c", suit);
   else if (rank = 6)
      printf("Six of %c", suit);
   else if (rank = 5)
      printf("Five of %c", suit); 
   else if (rank = 4)
      printf("Four of %c", suit);
   else if (rank = 3)
      printf("Three of %c", suit);
   else if (rank = 2)
      printf("Two of %c", suit);
   else
      printf("Not A valid entry");


   if(suit = 'H')
      suit ="Hearts";
   else if(suit = 'D')
      suit = "Diamonds";
   else if (suit = 'S') 
      suit = "Spades";
   else if (suit = 'C')
      suit = "Clubs";
   else
      printf("not a valid entry")




      return 0;



}
```

Comment: In C, a charcter is designated with single quotes. A blank would be `' '`. An `H` would be, `'H'`, etc. You'll get an error if you try, `char suit = "";` which is attempting to assign a string to a character, as your error points out. If you need something to represent "no suite", just use a zero or a blank. You might want to review your C fundamentals via book or tutorial before tacking this programming task. There are a lot of basic problems with the program.

Comment: `scanf("%d%c", rank, suit);` => `scanf("%d%c", &rank, &suit);`

Comment: `if (rank = xxx)` => `if (rank == xxx)`. The same for suits.

Comment: `suit = "Spades";` Is wrong. Suit is `char`, you can't assign string to it. Moreover, you can't assign strings like that as well.

Comment: if `suits == 'C'` -> `suits = "Clubs"` doesn't make sense and viceversa, because you are assigning `suits` to different types, and your program must behave very bad. In fact `char suits = "";` is wrong, you would know that if you use compiler warnings.

Comment: And consider use `switch/case` instead of `if/else if`

Comment: please do not use tabs when writing source code (unless the editor is set to convert all tabs to spaces.)  As you can see from the posted code, the tabs messed up the formatting of the code.

Comment: when calling scanf() (and family) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: there are two of 'printf("not a valid entry")'  but no indication of what exactly was a 'not a valid entry'.  Suggest making the text more descriptive by including 1) what the invalid data was, 2) if that was rank or suit that was not valid

Comment: the code is missing a key factor.  Specifically at the beginning, some printf's indicating what the program is expecting.  Otherwise the user will be looking at a blank screen and wondering what to do next.  'Enter card; does not tell the user the rank is 2...14 nor that suit is H,D,S,C.

Comment: this kind of line: ''char suit = "";' does not compile as the string "" (C degrades this to a pointer to char) is being assigned to a char named 'suit''  Suggest: char * suit = NULL;   Then the other places in the code where suit is accesses would also work.  Note: suit is being set to point to some string, like: 'Hearts" but is never being displayed/printed to the user.

Comment: if the rank and suit (after validation) were used to access a table, then only one printf() statement could cover all possibilites (except the erroneous input that was checked/caught/displayed during the validation.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the comparison operator `==` instead of the assignment operator `=` in your if statements.

e.g.

```
if(rank == 14)
```

instead of

```
if(rank = 14)
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for commenting! really helped! Switches were the way to go started from square one and got this to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

//Declarations
{
char suit = 0; 
int rank = 0; 

//Input


printf("This program converts shorthand notation for playing cards and converts\n");
printf("it into a sentence. Enter 14 for Ace 13 for King 12 For Queen and 11 for Jack.\n");
printf("enter S for Spade, C for Club, D for Diamond, and H for Hearts\n");
printf("\nEnter card shorthand: ");
scanf("%d%c", &rank, &suit);


switch(rank)   
 {
 case 14:
  printf("Ace");
  break;
 case 13:
  printf("King");
  break;
 case 12:
  printf("Queen");
  break;
 case 11:
  printf("Eleven");
  break;
 case 10:
  printf("Ten");
  break;
 case 9:
  printf("Nine");
  break;
 case 8:
  printf("Eight");
  break;
 case 7:
  printf("Seven");
  break;
 case 6:
  printf("Six");
  break;
 case 5:
  printf("Five");
  break;
 case 4:
  printf("Four");
  break;
 case 3:
  printf("Three");
  break;
 case 2:
  printf("Two");
  break;
 default:
  printf("Improper input");
  break;


}   

switch (suit)    // this switch converts the char value (suit) into a string.
{
 case 'h': case 'H':
   printf(" of Hearts");
   break;
 case 'd': case 'D':
   printf(" of Diamonds");
   break;
 case 's': case 'S':
   printf(" of Spades");
   break;
 case 'c': case 'C':
   printf(" of Clubs");
   break;

 default:
   printf(" try again");
   break;
}


return 0; 


}
```